# Getting NaN in a column after applying map() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace the categorical variable in the Gender column - M, F with 0, 1. However, after running my code I'm getting **NaN** in place of 0 & 1.

**Code-**

```
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].map({'F':1, 'M':0})
```

My input data frame-
[image]

Dataframe after running the code-
[image]

Details- Gender (Data Type) - object

Kindly, suggest a way out!

Comment: Are you sure the gender is just the string `'F'`, and that there are no white spaces around or something like that?

Comment: If you have whitespace in your strings, then `df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].str.strip().map({'F':1, 'M':0})` should work

Comment: You should provide only the relevant minimized example of your dataframe _as text_ so that people can copy it and test their solutions easily.

Comment: There aren't any whitespaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This particular code resolved the issue-

```
# Import label encoder
from sklearn import preprocessing
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
  
# Encode labels in column 'Gender'.
df['Gender']= label_encoder.fit_transform(df['Gender'])
df['Gender'].unique()
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe values in your dataframe are different from the expected strings 'F' and 'M'. Try to use [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) from SkLearn.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df['Gender'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['Gender'])
```